# Java Class.forName() method stalling and then exits

Tags: java, maven

I am at a loss as to what has happened to my code. This used to work:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass) Class.forName(extendedType).getConstructors()[0].newInstance(scan);
```

But now it is not loading. Instead it hits this line, stalls, and then exits. I have debugged it and know that is is happening somewhere in this line. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Earlier today I refactored my code and ever since it has been giving me some naming issues. Mainly i changed packages names from uppercase to lower case (ie. Myclass.class to myclass.class). I don't know if this has affected something or not.

**Update**
extendedType is a string providing the full package and class name of the class I want to load. So, for example, com.biz.myclass instead of just myclass. The intent is to load a child class of a parent class depending on what the user chooses. There are other ways of doing this, but I want to know why this suddenly stopped working. And it stalls on Class.forName

Comment: what value does `extendedType` contain?

Comment: I would separate the line into three lines and see where it actually "stalls" - is it `Class.forName()`, `getConstructors()`, or `newInstance()`?

Comment: See update to the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refactoring Package is not perfect in many IDEs, try not to...

try to check the actual folder names that exist in the system.

if the folder names are as they were before then you have your problem.

if the original package name was lets say:

> MyPackage

and then you refactored it to:

> mypackage

then you might have to manually go and rename you folder structure accordingly.

try it.